# Using indoor only power adapter outside

Tags: electrical, pool, weather-resistant

I'm setting up a mineralization unit for my pool. The unit came with a 12V1A power adapter which says Indoor Use Only on it. At the same time, the instructions say that the unit should be powered using an outlet that's wired directly into the timer for the pool pump, so that it only operates when the pump is cycling the water. I'm having an electrician add an outlet with a weatherproof cover. My question is, is having the power supply protected by a weatherproof box the same as using it indoors? I imagine the box protects against moisture. But what about heat and humidity? I cant seem to find a similar power adapter that would be rated for outdoors.

Comment: Can you get a different power adapter for the unit?

Answer (score 3):

Those waterproof covers are only rainproof. They are open at the bottom for the cords to go through so they are not moisture and humidity proof. Outdoor rated cords have a heavier, much heavier, insulation to protect them from the outdoor environment, sun, UV, animals,etc. The male and female ends are also insulated heavier and are of higher quality. Connecting to a weatherproof box is not the same as indoor use and if the outlet is outdoors, it will have to be GFCI protected.

Comment: I agree with Jack although I use those wall warts in my shop I would not want one used outside around the pool unless I had some more protection than an in use cover especially around water / pool chemicals.

Comment: @EdBeal Good point about the pool chemicals.